# Access several elements from list based on the indexes stored in another list

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is to extract elements from data frame column that contains list, imagine column df$A with 3 rows, each rows contains list:

```
c(111, 222, 333)
c(444, 555, 666)
c(777, 888, 999)
```

(lists vary from one to twenty-thirty elements)

while column df$B stores certain positions of elements:

```
1
c(1, 2)
c(1, 2, 3)
```

my goal is to extract to column df$C elements from column df$B, based on their index stored in column df$A, so the column df$C would look like

```
111
c(444, 555)
c(777, 888, 999)
```

I've already tried different combinations of unlist, sapply, mutate, accessing list elements with vector, like

```
df$A[nrow][[c(df$B)]]
```

and so on, but I keep on running into different errors and haven't gotten closer to desired result.

Finally, what I want to achieve, is to sum integers in each row on certain position on a list, so potential df$D might look like

```
111
999
2664
```

I am afraid that maybe my entire approach is wrong and I am forcing R to act in a way it was not designed to, but so far I usually managed to get right answers for every question I've asked myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about the whole data.frame contains lists thing:

data: (not recommended though) just use two lists (`l1` , `l2`)

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3)

df1$A <- list(c(111, 222, 333),
              c(444, 555, 666),
              c(777, 888, 999))

df1$B <- list(1,
              c(1, 2),
              c(1, 2, 3))
```

code: its time for `?mapply`.

```
#df1$D <-
mapply(function(vals, inds) {sum(vals[inds])}, vals = df1$A, inds = df1$B)
```

result:

```
#[1]  111  999 2664
```

Comment: It seems like a solution I've been looking for - I'll flag it as soon as I deal with my problem, that due to usage of strsplit my integers are stored as strings (haven't paid enough attention as I focused on get-element-by-index part of task), so obviously I can't sum them.

I appreciate your help though, I wish that one day I'll get to that level of thinking in R as you have presented here.

Comment: Okay, lapply(strsplit( ... ), as.numeric) has helped me in converting integers stored as strings to integers and then your solution has worked as expected. Many thanks for your help!